# kpssvc service won't start on DC

Tags: proxy, domain-controller, kerberos

I have a single domain with 2 sites, each site has it's own 2019 DC.  On the (secondary) site I see an alert that the KPSSVC service  (KDC Proxy Server Service) is not started.  And it's startup type is set to automatic.

When I try to start the service Windows replies with "Windows could not start the KDC Proxy Server service (KPSSVC) on the local computer.  Error 5: Access is denied".  I am trying to start the service while logged in as the domain admin.

I do not have any sub-OU's, this is a very simple domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be started. The KDC Proxy is intended to provide a bridge on member hosts for other hosts that may not have direct line of sight access to a domain controller. The KDC Proxy also needs to be configured with a certificate using netsh prior to use.

Comment: So should I disable the service?

Comment: Set it to manual. Or find out why it was changed.